# Inconsistent 433Mhz decoded results for same remote controller button clicks

Tags: gpio, python

Purpose

- Using RF receiver to capture signal from light switch remote controller within
- Using RF sender to emulate signal captured from remote controller to work with Homebridge

Result

- Same button clicks resulted a little bit different codes as per what graph showed

Python Code to capture signal from remote controller

```py
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import numpy as np
import pickle
import os.path
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    MAX_DURATION = 5
    RECEIVED_SIGNAL = None
    RECEIVED_SIGNAL = [[], []]
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    print 'GPIO setmode - pass'
    GPIO.setup(RECEIVE_PIN, GPIO.IN)
    print 'GPIO setup - pass'
    cumulative_time = 0
    beginning_time = datetime.now()
    print '**Started recording**'
    signal_1 = 0
    signal_2 = 0
    while cumulative_time < MAX_DURATION:
        time_delta = datetime.now() - beginning_time
        RECEIVED_SIGNAL[0].append(time_delta)
        signal_1 = GPIO.input(RECEIVE_PIN)
        if signal_2 != signal_1:
            signal_2 = signal_1
        RECEIVED_SIGNAL[1].append(signal_1)
        cumulative_time = time_delta.seconds
    print '**Ended recording**'
    GPIO.cleanup()
    print '**Processing results**'
    for i in range(len(RECEIVED_SIGNAL[0])):
        RECEIVED_SIGNAL[0][i] = RECEIVED_SIGNAL[0][i].seconds + RECEIVED_SIGNAL[0][i].microseconds/1000000.0

    print len(RECEIVED_SIGNAL[0]), 'samples recorded'
    print '**Plotting results**'
    print "length : {}, {}".format(len(RECEIVED_SIGNAL[0]), len(RECEIVED_SIGNAL[1]))

    pyplot.plot(RECEIVED_SIGNAL[0], RECEIVED_SIGNAL[1])
    pyplot.axis([0, MAX_DURATION, -1, 2])
    pyplot.show()
```

**pushed button on remote controller 6 times**

[image]

**zoom in 1, 2, 3 button click graph**
[image]
[image]
[image]

Even though same button clicked multiple time, it shows a bit different signals on graph. Am I doing wrong with capturing signal? Where's long_on, long_off, short_off, short_on?

Ref: http://www.instructables.com/id/Super-Simple-Raspberry-Pi-433MHz-Home-Automation/

Comment: See if http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python__433_py is more reliable,

Comment: Thanks @joan, I will look into it and post if there's any significant result with it.